# Clarification on postfix/prefix operators on iterators

Tags: c++

In `Accelerated C++` by `Andrew Koenig` he writes the following code for introduction to templates and generic functions.  Does this code skip the first element in the container?  Or does it copy the first iterator object before incrementing:

```
template<class In, class Out>
Out copy(In begin, In end, Out dest)
{
while (begin != end)
    *dest++ = *begin++;
return dest;
}
```

In other words, does this behave just as his code?:

```
template<class In, class Out>
Out copy(In begin, In end, Out dest)
{
while (begin != end)
    *dest = *begin;
    dest++;  begin++;
return dest;
}
```

Comment: my only thought is that I wonder if the increment order is left unspecified in `*dest++ = *begin++` but you've given an order to the post-increment in the second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post incrementing an iterator (or anything else for that matter) may look confusing but what it is doing is pretty straight forward. It makes a copy of the value, increments the original and then returns the copy. So the location being referred to with "*dest++" is the same as "*dest", the only difference is that after the statement finishes dest will now refer to the next iteration in the iteratable.

The only problems with this arise when programmers use the incremented variable repeatedly in the same expression. (Which is usually only used as a brain teaser and the resulting effect varies from language to language)